# NodeJs + Websockets How to achieve the following scenario?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I have a following scenario with NodeJs + websockets. (websocket module)

I have a form with three fields (username, password, hostname). Upon submit , it will span a connection to a web ssh terminal and input the password automatically. To input the password, I'm using the the following :

```
    setTimeout(function(){
            term.write(password);
            term.write('\r');},3000);
    }
```

These username, password, hostname variables will be extracted from the http request body (req.body) and passed on the socket connection as below.

```
// from the app.post 
sshuser = req.body.username;
sshhost = req.body.hostname;
password = req.body.password;


conn.on('message', function(msg) {

    var data = JSON.parse(msg.utf8Data);
    if (!term) {
       term = pty.spawn('ssh', [sshuser +'@'+ sshhost], {
                name: 'xterm-256color',
                cols: 80,
                rows: 30
            });

        // Password Input         
        setTimeout(function(){
                term.write(password);
                term.write('\r');},3000);
```

Now, the problem I face is :

Two clients(user1 and user2) connected to the socket server and submitted the form at the same time.

**form variables from User1**

- username : root
- hostname: testhost1
- password: mypassowrd1

**form variables from User2**

- username : root
- hostname : testhost2
- password : mypassword2

Within this three second time frame (used by setTimeout to input password automatically) , the **password** variable will be set to **mypassword2** . So the user2's login will be succeeded and user1's login will be failed(password wrong).

Is there any way to circumvent this situation?

Comment: You need to show more of your code. It's all about scope. Declaring the variable INSIDE the http callback function will essentially create a new variable every time the callback is fired because it creates a new scope. This means you have more than one instance of that variable and so the password won't get "overwritten". When accessing the password variable it's using the local scope from that http request rather than a different scope from a different http request. It's kind of hard to explain and even more difficult to understand but if you post code someone can clarify it for you.

Comment: why are you using a timeout anyways.  If you are using sockets and streams everything should be evented.

Comment: @Randy , I'll try to post the entire code, code is somewhat big, I need to cut it down.